# How to make `JSInvokable` method to behave like event handler - render parent component

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

Please, check following demo for repo: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GlkBFqbH07Y1YMo029

I have a custom component that uses JS Interop to call from JS to Component Instance.

I use it like this:

```
<EditForm Model=this>
    <CustomInput @bind-Value="value" />
    <div>IsModified: @(context.IsModified())</div>
</EditForm>
```

When I call following code from standard blazor event handler:

```
public void Increment()
{
    Value++;
    _ = ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression));
}
```

parent component is rerendered after the event handler is done.

However, when I call it from JS:

```
[JSInvokable]
public void IncrementJsInterop() => Increment();
```

The parent component is rerendered immediately, after the ValueChanged callback is invoked. Howerver, any changes to EditContext (e.g IsModified), are not reflected, because they happen only after the callback, see Increment() method.

How to make `JSInvokable` method to behave like event handler?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two "events" are handled differently in Blazor.

I added some console writes to see what's executed when.

```cs
<button type="button" @onclick="Increment">Increment using C# Event handler</button>
```

looks like this (`>> false` is the state of `IsModified`)

```
=================Increment - Called >> False
=> Increment - Value++ >> False
=> Increment - ValueChanged.InvokeAsync >> False
++++> ShouldRender Called >> False
=> Increment - EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged >> False
=================Increment - Completed >> True
++++> Render Fragment Run >> True
OnAfterRender >> True
```

While

```cs
 <button type="button" @ref="btnElementRef">Increment using JS Interop</button>
```

looks a little different - note where Render Fragment Run happens.

```
=================IncrementJsInterop - Called >> False
=================Increment - Called >> False
=> Increment - Value++ >> False
=> Increment - ValueChanged.InvokeAsync >> False
++++> ShouldRender Called >> False
++++> Render Fragment Run >> False
=> Increment - EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged >> False
=================Increment - Completed >> True
=================IncrementJsInterop - Completed >> True
OnAfterRender >> True
```

The normal Blazor Renderer event handler looks something like this:

```cs
var task = InvokeAsync(HandlerMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

In the Event sequence we see `ValueChanged` trigger the render in the parent component, however the Rendered doesn't actually run the render until `Increment` completes.

In `IncrementJsInterop` we see `ValueChanged` trigger the render in the parent component, but in this instance the Renderer immediately renders the component.  As `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged` hasn't yet run, it's false when the parent is rendered.

Both are actually JsInterop "events", but the `Renderer` is handling them slightly differently.

This fix works in the example but doesn't solve the problem as many things that rely on looking up the value in the model get triggered when a `FieldChanged` event occurs.

```
    public async Task Increment()
    {
        Value++;
        EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression));
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
```

`EditContext` now knows about the field change before any rendering triggered by inter-component updates happen.

===============================================

My Revised re-jigged test code is:

###### Component:

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<div style="border: solid; padding: 1em">
    CustomInput <br />
    Value: @Value
    <button type="button" @ref="btnElementRef">Increment using JS Interop</button>
    <button type="button" @onclick="Increment">Increment using C# Event handler</button>
</div>

<script suppress-error="BL9992">

    function init(dotNetRef, elementRef) {
        elementRef.addEventListener('click', () => {
            setTimeout(() => dotNetRef.invokeMethodAsync('IncrementJsInterop'), 50);
        });
    }
</script>

@code {
    ElementReference btnElementRef;
    DotNetObjectReference<TestJSCaller> dotNetRef;

    [Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter] EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<int>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback ValueUpdated { get; set; }

    public async Task Increment()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"=================Increment - Called >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"=> Increment - Value++ >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
        Value++;
        Console.WriteLine($"=> Increment - ValueChanged.InvokeAsync >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
        Console.WriteLine($"=> Increment - EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
        EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression));
        Console.WriteLine($"=================Increment - Completed >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task IncrementJsInterop() {
        Console.WriteLine($"=================IncrementJsInterop - Called >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
        await Increment();
        Console.WriteLine($"=================IncrementJsInterop - Completed >> {EditContext.IsModified()}");
    }


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
        {
            dotNetRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JS!.InvokeVoidAsync("init", dotNetRef, btnElementRef);
        }
    }
}
```

###### Page

```
@page "/Test4"
<h1>Hello, Blazor REPL!</h1>

When you click "Increment using JS Interop" the IsModified: False is not rerendered.
When you click it again, it refreshed to true.
<br />
<br />

This is different from "Increment using C# Event handler".
<br />
<br />
@this.testFrag


<EditForm EditContext="this.editcontext">
    <TestJSCaller @bind-Value="@model.Value" ValueUpdated="ValueUpdated"/>

    <div>
        Value in Main Component: @model.Value
    </div>

    <div>IsModified: @(editcontext.IsModified())</div>
    <div>RenderCounter: @(renderCounter)</div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private int renderCounter = 1;
    private DataModel model = new DataModel();

    protected EditContext editcontext;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.editcontext = new EditContext(model);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OnAfterRender >> {editcontext.IsModified()}");
    }

    protected void ValueUpdated()
        => StateHasChanged();

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"++++> ShouldRender Called >> {editcontext.IsModified()}");
        renderCounter++;
        return true;
    }

    public class DataModel
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    private RenderFragment testFrag => (builder) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"++++> Render Fragment Run >> {editcontext.IsModified()}");
        builder.AddContent(0, $"Is Mod: {editcontext.IsModified()}");
    };

}
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm owner of the CustomInput component, not the consuming code.

Comment: Question: In you second paragraph _"which includes a calling StateHasChanged on the component and parent."_, what you meant by parent? The Click event is defined on Button element and eventhandler is defined in CustomInput component. It does not explain, why the Main component is rerendered after EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged is called.

Comment: @Liero  See the updated answer for my answers to your two comments.  My initial assumption about the event handling was on the right track, but further investigation lead to further enlightenment!

Comment: RE: "Fix": I can't notify EditContext about a change before the change actually happens.  That would be a disaster for the consument :) But I guess I could override the should render method to delay rendering

Comment: [Polite]?????  In the example code `Value++;` sets the new value.  `Notify...` tells the `EditContext` that the value has changed, and `ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value)` tells the parent component the value has changed.

Comment: Not exactly. `Notify...` doesn't tell the EditContext that the `Value` has changed, but in your case that `() => model.Value` has changed and that isn't true until the ValueChanged callback is invoked.

Comment: @Liero - by `Value` I mean the `Value` in the control, which is what you want to apply to the model.  I called it a Fix rather than the Solution because I could foresee situations where say an `EditContext` `OnFieldChanged` event was used to do something that looked up the model value.  I've not yet had the inclination to dig deep into the `Renderer` code to understand fully what's going on.   `InputBase` does it the way you did initially.

Comment: For example, every blazor validator listens to OnFieldChanged and looks up the model value

Comment: Agreed.  Fixes the example, but not in the real world. So back to square one.   I've amended the answer.